# OnBlur firing multiple times

Tags: javascript

I am using `onblur` for text box data checking. OnBlur is working fine until or unless we are not pressing `ALT + TAB or windows button`.

If I pressed  `ALT + TAB` then blur function executing multiple times..

For example : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_blur_alert

> Initially it will work fine then press alt+tab then it will execute
>   multiple times.

Please suggest how to resolved this issue.

> Please follow below steps to re produce the issue
>
> 1. Click on the above link
> 2. Focus on the text box and then press `alt+tab`

Comment: The mentioned link shows 1 alert for both the cases. Can you please create a stack snippet that simulates the issue?

Comment: @Rajesh I have mentioned steps to re produce the issue. Focus on the text box and then press alt + tab

Comment: If you read my comment, I said *The mentioned link shows 1 alert for both the cases* This means I tried it already.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are prompting an alert on blur, when you press `alt+tab` it will focus on different window and when you click on alert box it will again focus to text field and will cause fire an event, This will do infinity.
You should avoid alert here

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").blur(function(){
        console.log("This input field has lost its focus.");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter your name: <input type="text">
<p>Write something in the input field, and then click outside the field to lose focus (blur).</p>
```

Comment: Any other solution with alert()?

Comment: if you want to prompt message than you need to consider other library for it and not to use native prompt.

Comment: Can you share any information for other library which will support in ie8

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty checkout jquery-confirm plugin https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/